# URL amigável em PHP com htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Bom dia,

Eu estou criando um sistema simples em `PHP` pra aprender mais sobre `MVC`. Gostaria de recuperar da URL a informação contida em '?pag='. Como fazer isso? Preciso alterar meu arquivo `.htaccess`?

Eu quero que a URL fique como controller/action/param/?pag=0

Bootstrap.php

```html
<?php

class Bootstrap
{
    private $controller = 'indexController';
    private $action     = 'index';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if (isset($url[0])) {
            if (file_exists(CONTROLLERS . $url[0] . 'Controller.php')) {
                $this->controller = $url[0] . 'Controller';
            }
        }

        if (isset($url[1])) {
            $this->action = $url[1];
        }

        require_once CONTROLLERS . $this->controller . '.php';
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;
        $this->controller->{$this->action}();
    }

    private function parseUrl()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
            $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
            $url = explode('/', $url);

            return $url;
        }
    }
}
```

.htacess:

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Não exatamente. Há uma diferença: neste caso existe um roteamento para controller/action/param para então vir uma outra variável.

Comment: Amigo, basta aplicar o mesmo conceito do parâmetro `page`, mas atualizei aquela resposta adicionado o conceito "MVC".